# Django not saving forms data in database

Tags: django

I am getting forms success message in my html template but forms data not saving. here is my code:

**views.py:**

```
 class BlogDetailsAccount(FormMixin,DetailView):
          model = Blog
          template_name = 'blog/my-account-blog-details.html'
          form_class = CommentFrom
         
          def get_success_url(self):
            return reverse('blog:my-account-blog-details', kwargs={'slug': self.object.slug})
      
          def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
              #my context data........
              
              return data
          
          def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            self.object = self.get_object()
            form = self.get_form()
            if form.is_valid():
                messages.add_message(self.request, messages.INFO, 'Your Comment pending for admin approval')
                return self.form_valid(form)
            else:
                messages.add_message(self.request, messages.INFO, 'Somethings Wrong. Please try again')
                return self.form_invalid(form)
    
          def form_valid(self, form):
            return super(BlogDetailsAccount, self).form_valid(form)
```

my **models.py**:

```
class BlogComment(models.model):
     .......#my models fields.... 
     .............

post_save.connect(BlogComment.user_comment, sender=BlogComment)  #using signals
```

Comment: A `formMixin` does *not* save the data to the database.

Comment: Willem Van Onsem what I need to be do for save data?

Comment: Why don't you simply use an `UpdateView`? you don't even need to inherit from `DetailView` in that case since it will pass the object to the view.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat: I think the form is to create a comment, whereas the view displays a blog, so the form does not match the object of the `DetailView`.

Comment: @boyenec please make sure your edits don't invalidate answers. See [“What to do when someone answers” - Don't be a chameleon, don't be a vandal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332820/what-to-do-when-someone-answers-dont-be-a-chameleon-dont-be-a-vandal). You may edit, but edit in such a way that it doesn't invalidate existing answers.

Comment: Abdul Aziz Barkat I am new. Thanks for the suggestion next time I will be more careful

Comment: Note that since your problem isn't solved (it is the same problem) you _can_ edit your question a bit, but make it obvious, example: "As suggested in below answer I tried ... but XYZ happens", don't completely remove the original question, just add on to it.

Comment: Abdul Aziz Barkat  okay...  got it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `FormMixin` does *not* save the data to the database. In case you need to save the form, you should save it in the `form_valid` method:

A `form_mixin` does *not* save the data to the database.

```
class BlogDetailsAccount(FormMixin,DetailView):
    # …

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.get_form()  # ← first create a form
        self.object = self.get_object()  # ← then specify the object
        if form.is_valid():
            messages.add_message(self.request, messages.INFO, 'Your Comment pending for admin approval')
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            messages.add_message(self.request, messages.INFO, 'Somethings Wrong. Please try again')
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

You should also likely fill in relevant data like the post where the comment appears and

Comment: I tried `form.save()` before posting the question but didn't work. I am getting this error `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'author'` I think I need to pass author id inside view but I am not understanding how

Comment: @boyenec: edit the question with the *full* traceback, share the form you are using.

Comment: @boyenec: you can work with `form.instance.author = self.request.user` *before* saving the form.

Comment: @boyenec it is likely from your signal, you seem to define it on your _model_ which is a bad practice, define it in a separate file.

Comment: Willem Van Onsem `form.instance.author = self.request.user` I tried but still now getting same error.  Abdul Aziz Barkat  I think so. Most probably signal can't find author id which I am using as user.

Comment: @boyenec: you should avoid signals as much as possible: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/signals.html

Comment: Willem Van Onsem I almost solve the problem see my updated questiion. Now data saving to data base. But now getting this error `NOT NULL constraint failed: notifications_notifications.sender_id`

Comment: @boyenec: well it looks like your form should send a notification, but does not know to/from what user. We thus likely need to know the implementation of the form and the `Notification` model.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem my problem solved. I was doing mistake here `form.instance.author = self.request.user` it will be `form.instance.user = self.request.user` as I was using user fields and author was for another model.